# Add custom parameters in SoundClound embed

Tags: embed

I use oEmbedd functionality of WordPress. All work fine but I need to set custom parameters in the iframe

So I try this without success :

```
function my_oembed_fetch_url( $provider, $url, $args ) {
    // You can find the list of defaults providers in WP_oEmbed::__construct()
    if ( strpos( $provider, 'soundcloud.com' ) !== false) {

        if ( isset( $args['show_artwork'] ) ) {
            $provider = add_query_arg( 'show_artwork', absint( $args['show_artwork'] ), $provider );
        }
    }

    return $provider;
}

wp_oembed_get('https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/number-exampleXXXXXXX', array('show_artwork' => 'false'));
```

What's wrong ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the filter in your code to utilize "my_oembed_fetch_url" ?

```
add_filter( 'oembed_fetch_url', 'my_oembed_fetch_url', 10, 3 );
```